# How to target all .html URLS except index.html in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, permalinks

I currently have this in my Wordpress htaccess file:

```html
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    #RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1/
```

I am trying to redirect all .html to just the URL without any file extension, i.e www.example.com/about.html to www.example.com/about/.

The code works fine where the /index.html redirects to /

The commented code above (`RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1/`) should work for redirect .html to the pretty URLS but it's also doing it for the index.html where instead of redirecting it to / it redirects it to /index

Is there a way for my to condense my code and do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]

# redirect every .html except index.html
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.html$)(.+)\.html?$ /$1 [NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```